# Using group_concat with sum of case when in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get SQL result in the following format:

```
+------------+--------------+
|   regions| quarter_values| 
+------------+--------------+
|    A     |  0,2,0,2      | 
|    B     |  1,3,4,5      |  
|    C     |  2,6,2,0      |  
+------------+--------------+
```

But with the below query,  it gives  **`Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`**

```
  SELECT r.regions,       
          group_concat( 
          sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
          sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
          sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
          sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) as 'quarter_values'    
           FROM  requests r group by r.regions;
```

Any help with this query?

Comment: Can you share the raw data you want to get this result for?

Comment: @Mureinik I want to use this data for highcharts sparkline graph.

Comment: the request table contains requests with ids, request_type, date created and few other values.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest aggregation functions.

But you don't need to use `GROUP_CONCAT`, just ordinary concatenation.

```
SELECT regions, 
    CONCAT_WS(',',
      sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
      sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
      sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
      sum( CASE WHEN r.request_type="create" and quarter(created_at)= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    ) as quarter_values
FROM requests r 
group by r.regions;
```